# How to resolve Error LNK2019 when use webrtc.lib in visual studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, webrtc

I was trying build webrtc source into `webrtc.lib` file by using:

```
gn gen out/DebugX64 --winsdk="10.0.19041.0" --ide="vs2019" --args="ffmpeg_branding=\"Chrome\" proprietary_codecs=true is_debug=true target_cpu=\"x64\" is_component_build=false "
ninja -C out/DebugX64
```

Then I link it in project (visual studio 2019), then compile an example in webrtc and get bulk of error LNK2019 such as:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At2f0.png)

Note:
I added `webrtc.lib; WS2_32.lib; secur32.lib; winmm.lib; dmoguids.lib; wmcodecdspuuid.lib; msdmo.lib; Strmiids.lib` in **Linker>input>Additional Dependencies**, and `C:\Users\User\Desktop\webrtc-checkout\src\out\DebugX64\obj` in **Linker>general>Additional Library Directories**

Comment: Are you using the same runtime library (MultiThread, MultiThreadDLL, etc.) to build your application that `webrtc` was built with?  Also, you should post, as text, the actual error, not just the error number.

Comment: Also, make sure the project configuration you added the .lib files to as linker dependencies is the one you are actually building.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir yes, my project configuration is correct

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks, but how to know what runtime library built with webrtc? I just see some dll file like: ``api-ms-win-core-xxxx.dll`` in out/DebugX64 directory

Comment: *but how to know what runtime library built with webrtc?* -- Open the Visual Studio IDE to your project, go to the project settings and go to the C/C++ Code Generation and Runtime Library.  All of your modules should be using the same library.

Comment: *yes, my project configuration is correct* -- How do we know this, unless we can see these settings ourselves?  What may look "correct" to you could be wrong.

Comment: Have you added the header files related to .lib?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT yes, I added all header files

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried all option at ``Runtime Library``, even I just write a simple code such as
```
#include <iostream>
#include <absl/strings/str_split.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> v = absl::StrSplit("a,b,c", ',');
    for (auto var : v) std::cout << var;
    std::cout << "hello";
    return 0;
}
```
it also get similar error: https://pastebin.com/M92p4Wre

Comment: From the library you add, you may be mixing x64 and x32. Please check your project configuration.
If you can show your project configuration, it will help to solve the problem.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT here is my project, could you review it help me? many thanks! https://drive.google.com/file/d/106wSn4Ku2q6zhcvJ2chZ8PdKEMhhu9Ka/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @dvik I did not find <str_split.h> in the folder.  Do you have this file in your project?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT yes, it have in my project. Now I can use webrtc.lib by using this pre-build https://github.com/iimachines/webrtc-build. So, I think this problem not from project config, it come from build process (gn gen ...; ninja -C ...). May be i didn't understand flags of ``gn gen`` command